# Java / Android: How to work with return type 'List<MyType>'?

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist, return

My problem is about Java / Android :

I created a class `MyClass` which has a method `getAllData()` that returns an `List<MyType> = new ArrayList<MyType>()`. In an other class `MyOtherClass` I call to this method and want to write the returned List into another `List<MyType>`.

But I get the following error: *Unhandled exception type Exception*

What can I do about this?

Here's the code:

**MyClass.java**

```
 public List<MyType> datas = new ArrayList<MyType>();

public List<MyType> getAllData() throws Exception{

//add some things to datas... 

return datas;
}
```

**MyOtherClass.java**

```
 public void fetchData(){

    MyClass mydatas = new MyClass();
    List<MyType> thedatas = mydatas.getAllData();

 }
```

How can I solve the problem?
With an "try / catch(Exception e)" surrounding the statement, it seems not to get the returned List from `getAllData();`

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You have  MyClass and MyOtherClass but the question is, do you have your type MyType? :D

Comment: yes of course I have MyType defined. Thanks anyway. @Mark Byers: What exactly do you mean? I cannot compile so I get this message from Eclipse directly in the code next to the line where I set 'List<MyType> thedatas=mydatas.getAllData();'. It suggests me to wrap a try/catch block around this. So 'try{ List<MyType> thedatas... } catch (Exception e){}' but this does not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `getAllData()` *might* throws a checked exception (i.e., an exception that is not a `RunTimeException`), you have to surround the statement with `try-catch`

```
public void fetchData() {
    MyClass mydatas = new MyClass();
    try {
        List<MyType> thedatas = mydatas.getAllData();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // display or log exception name
    }
}
```

Or add `throws` clause after the method name.

```
public void fetchData() throws Exception {
    MyClass mydatas = new MyClass();
    List<MyType> thedatas = mydatas.getAllData();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's right. I did this but it did not work. The reason why it did not work was, that the method `getAllData();` threw an exception...  But maybe it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

You declare the `getAllData` method to throw `Exception`. The compiler is now asking you what to do if an exception of type Exception is thrown.

You should NEVER throw `Exception` as part of a method signature. It is too general. Instead you should try to throw only the specific exceptions that may occur.

If you do not wish `fetchData` to have to deal with exceptions then you must either declare `fetchData` to throw the same exceptions OR make `getAllData` catch the exceptions and return an appropriate value if an exception is thrown.